# add Nginx 1.20.1 GeoIP2 module

Tags: nginx, geoip, geoip2, nginx-module

I'm trying to `configure` nginx to build the GeoIP2 module, by following this installation:
https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module

first I still didn't understand what is defrences between `static` and `dynamic` modules,
and why can't I just `apt install` that module..

The problemm is that I want to build/create it on a diffrent machine, so I had to copy the `configure` flags from the destination machine by copy the output of this command:

```
nginx -V
```

and then I ran this command on the test machine:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/" ./configure --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module --add-module=/path/ngx_http_geoip2_module-3.3 (PASTE DESTINATION NGINX -V OUTPUT)
make
make install
```

Then after succession I copied the file name: `ngx_http_geoip2_module.so` to destination machine
and ran `nginx -t`
I got this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] module "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My destination machine:
Ubuntu 20
Nginx 1.20.1

Answer (score 1):

--with-compat --add-module=/path/to/ngx_http_geoip2_module

or

--with-compat --add-dynamic-module=/path/to/ngx_http_geoip2_module

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add `--with-compat` option. Here are the commands I used to build it on **Almalinux 9.1**:

```
git clone https://github.com/nginx/nginx.git
git clone https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module.git
cd nginx
git checkout release-1.22.1 # or whatever version you have
auto/configure --with-compat --with-stream --add-dynamic-module=../ngx_http_geoip2_module `nginx -V`
make
cp objs/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so /usr/lib64/nginx/modules/
cp objs/ngx_stream_geoip2_module.so /usr/lib64/nginx/modules/
```